Is this enough to argue that the function is not continuous?
In order to argue that the function
$$
f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\qquad f(x)=\begin{cases}x, & x\leq 0\\x-2, & x>0\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous in $x=0$, is it enough to say that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0-}f(x)=0\neq -2=\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)?
$$
Found this argument in a book but for me it is unsatisfying in some sense... why does that already imply that the function is not continuous in $x=0$? Neither the epsilon-delta criterion nor the sequential criterion for continuity has been used at this point, or? Isn't that incomplete?

The epsilons and deltas are hidden in the $\lim_{x\to 0}$ notation.

I would have zero complaints about this argument.  Who is the audience?

Yes, it is enough. If both limits $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ exist and are distinct, then the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist (because if it did, then it would be equal to those two other limits). And if $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist, then, in particular, we cannot have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)$. Therefore, $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Ok, I now see the point. But, on the other hand, if for some function, $\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)=f(a)=\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)$ why does that imply that $f$ is continuous in $x=a$? Of course this means that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ but I do not see how this implies the sequential criterion (because of the "for all sequences" part of it), although it is very similar.

Does this answer your question?

No, it does not answer my question or at least I still do not understand how $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ is equivalent to the sequential definition of continuity.

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. And let $(a_n){n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of elements of the domain of $f$ such that $\lim{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then, since $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. And since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies|a-a_n|<\delta$. But then $n\geqslant N\implies|f(a)-f(a_n)|<\varepsilon$. This proves that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(a)$.

Now, suppose that you don't have $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. Then, for some $\varepsilon>0$, if you take any $\delta>0$, there is some $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ and that $|f(x)-f(a)|\geqslant\varepsilon$. In particular, for any $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some $a_n$ in the domain of $f$ such that $|a_n-a|<1/n$ and that $|f(a_n)-f(a)|\geqslant\varepsilon$. So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, but you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(a)$.

Thanks a lot. That was very helpful!

By the way: Am I right that using this definition of continuity, i.e., $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ is only advantageous in practice if one can actually compute the limit (or the limit from above and below)? For instance, if I want to show that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\begin{cases}x, & x\in\mathbb{Z}\0, & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is not continuous in $x=1$, say,  isn't it hard to actually compute $\lim_{x\to 1-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1+}f(x)$ so that it might be better to use, for example, the sequential definition of continuity?

That's the definition of continuity that I usually work with.

No! I misunderstood your question. The one I usually work with is the one with limits.

Really? Interesting. How do you use the one with limits in order to show that, for example, $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise is not continuous?

I shall prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $1$. In order to do that, I take an arbitrary $\delta>0$. Then I take a non-integer $x\in(1,1+\delta)$. Then $|x-1|<\delta$, but $|f(x)-f(1)|=|0-1|=1$. So, if $\varepsilon=1$, I have proved that$$(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x\in\Bbb R):|x-1|<\delta\text{ and }|f(x)-f(1)|\geqslant\varepsilon.$$

Yes, this is similar to what I did. But since you said you usually work with the limit definition I was wondering how you would use that definition here. :-)

Well, by definition asserting that $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\ne f(1)$ means that$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x\in D_f):|x-1|<\delta\text{ and }|f(x)-f(1)|\geqslant\varepsilon.$$And that is what I have proved.
